# Manifolds with Betti numbers like a projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Is there a classification of integers $k>0$ such that there can be a simply connected closed $4k$-manifold $M$ with $b_0(M)=b_{2k}(M)=b_{4k}(M)=1$ and all other betti numbers $0$? (I don't mind if there is some torsion in some of the integral homology)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as rational projective planes. Su has studied these and found many dimensions in which they exist or don't exist. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.07892.pdf for one of her papers on the subject. Also this talk by Zagier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLEWKDtCPTU announces the dimensions less than a million in which these things can exist.